# multiple listFragments with customized adapter in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment, viewgroup

I have a main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
```

auto generated by Eclipse with two tabs, and also I have created two ListFragments to be shown on each tab (also auto generated by Eclipse and I have added my codes and did not delete any overridden methods)

```
public class FragA extend ListFragment {
  private List<TypeA> list_A;
  private ArrayAdapter<TypeA> adapter;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  list1=new ArrayList<TypeA>();
  list1= /*gets data from db*/
  adapter = new My_A_Adapter(getActivity(),list_A);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
}


private class My_A_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<TypeA>{
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
public My_A_Adapter (FragA activity){
super(activity, R.layout.myItemView, list_A)
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 if(convertView==null){
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myItemView_A, parent, false)}
   /* defining the views as setting them by iterating over the list
      getting the data by position*/
  return convertView;
}
```

and the same approach for FragB , but the **FragB list get populated by android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** and not by customized myItemView

I think there is problem with context or some activity attributes (the Strings shown on the list are correct but the view is not mine !!)
can any one help me ? thanks

***FragB and its adapter is exactly the same code just where ever you see "A" replace with "B"***

Comment: Please post the code for FragB with it's Adapter.

Comment: it is exactly the same just replace A's with B's

Comment: **"FragB list get populated by andoir_simple_list"** - what does that mean? What is "andoir_simple_list"?

Comment: @Squonk  I mean android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead A_Adapter and the same with B_Adapter:

```
private class My_A_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<TypeA>{
    private Context context;

    public My_A_Adapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId){
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.myItemView,null)
        }
        /* defining the views as setting them by iterating over the list
        getting the data by position*/
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually as long as I understood in ListFragment there is no way to pass Context except getActivity(), so changing the constructor of My_A_Adapater from Activity to Context does not make any change , actually I committed what you said but the same problem !

Comment: I edited code, in last one not only constructor has changed, try please the last version, it should solve your problem.

Comment: I guess there must be a problem with ViewGroup Hierarchy , or Context get mixed with first fragment Context , or getActivity returns the MainActivity Context or something like this

Comment: If the problem is not solved, please post full code, with MainActivity, B_Fragment and B_Adapter.

Comment: Check please, that you use B_Adapter in B_Fragment.